# Properties of inverse of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\pi(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \pi_k z^k$. We assume that $\pi(z) \neq 0$ for all $|z| \leq 1$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^s |\pi_k| < \infty$ for some $s \geq 1$. I have two questions:

**Question 1**: In a paper that I am reading, the author defines $\alpha(z) = \pi(z)^{-1}$ and says that $\alpha(z)$ has the expansion $\alpha(z) = 1 - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha_k z^k$. I am wondering why does $\alpha(z)$ admit such expansion? Is it because that we can prove $\pi(z)$ to be holomorphic and nonzero on some open set $U$ containing the unit disk, and so $\alpha(z)$ is holomorphic on $U$ as well? I can only see that the convergence radius is 1 and do not know how it can be generalized to $1+\varepsilon$.

**Question 2**: The author also claims that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^s |\alpha_k| < \infty$. Is there any theorem entailing this convergence?

Answer (score 1):

I’m feeling too lazy and overstuffed to answer in detail. But maybe the following start will help. My strategy is to work formally, and keep track of convergence data as I go.

Writing $\Pi(z)=\sum_0^\infty\pi_kz^k$, the hypotheses imply that $\Pi(0)=\pi_0\ne0$. Thus $\pi_0^{-1}\Pi(z)=1+\sum_1^\infty\tau_kz^k=1+T(z)$, with $T$ having same domain of convergence as $\Pi$. Now the reciprocal of $1+T$ is $1+\sum_1^\infty(-T)^k$, and I’m going to have to leave all the rest, especially the computation of the domain of convergence, to you.